# Adding a non .net (static) web project to a Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to add a static web folder as a project in Visual Studio?

I have a VS solution with a number of sites and services, I also have a static html/JS/backbone site with no .net/cshtml content which I would like to be logically in this solution, and edited in VS.

is this possible?

Answer (score 19):

Create a physical folder with your web site in it.

then right click on solution, add existing web site, and select the folder

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a new solution folder, and add your files under there.

Comment: The solution folder is only a virtual folder. if i then added files to it they wouldn't physically be in any folder under the solution folder